# How to disable WebSocket by JS

Tags: javascript, websocket, websecurity

Is there a way to ensure that no js module in my app uses WebSocket?

I'm writing a web-app, where data safety is very important. But I'm using many third-party libraries, so any of them can hypothetically send user's data away. I can intercept all http connections by service worker. But ServiceWorker doesn't intercept WebSockets.

I consider using WebSocket = undefined in my main js file, but is there a way to restore this global variable somehow later, when I import a module with malicious code?

Comment: You need content security policies : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src . Don't try to implement security features yourself, it can always be bypassed, use the features the browser provide

Comment: And also keep in mind that it's possible to obtain a fresh and untampered window or document object, with all browser api's on it. You can use an iframe for that for example, and i'm sure there is many other ways, so doing `WebSocket = undefined` won't do anything. And i'm sure a hacker can easily terminate your worker